# Convert character array to float?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a very basic command line C++ application that takes arguments on execution.

I just started C++ today, and it seems apparent that you can only take `char**` as the data type for arguments. I want to take two `float`s as parameters (to add them together later), but I can't seem to cast the character arrays as floats.

I have tried `static_cast<float>(argv[0])` and `stof(argv[0])` to cast the values, and both give compiler errors (unable to cast and not defined in scope, respectively).

I'm using the `Code::Blocks IDE` if that answers any questions.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

/**
 * author: 2mac
 *
 */

using namespace std;

void derp();
float getSum(float num1, float num2);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    float num1 = static_cast<float>(argv[0]);
    float num2 = static_cast<float>(argv[1]);

    if (argc != 0 || argc != 2)
        cout << "Usage: hello-world [args]\nargs: none OR <num1> <num2> to be added together" << endl;
    else
    {
        switch (argc)
        {
        case 0:
            derp();
            break;
        case 2:
            derp();
            cout << num1 << " + " << num2 << " equals " << getSum(num1,num2) << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void derp()
{
    cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    cout << "It's time to lern some C++!" << endl;
}

float getSum(float num1, float num2)
{
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

Comment: argv[0] will be the name of your program. Use argv[1] for the first argument, argv[2] for the second, etc. But, anytime you are using argv[1...n] you should make a check that argc is large enough. It always has a value of at least 1 (program name is always in argv[0]) and is incremented by 1 for each argument on the command line. So your check should be if with regard to argc == 1 or 3, not 0 and 2. Your check also appears to be incorrect. != with an or.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this to convert your input to float number,

```
double f1, f2;
if (argc == 2)
{
    f1 = atof (argv[0]);
    f2 = atof (argv[1]);
}
```

Comment: The compiler gives me grief for this. Similar to before, `atof` isn't defined in the scope.

Comment: You need to **#include <stdlib.h>**

Comment: If this is C++, **don't** use stdlib.h. Use `cstdlib` instead.

Answer (score 1):

A `char**` in C++ is just that, an pointer to a pointer to a character, thus not convertable to a `float` (Or any numeric value for that matter) directly Thus your first example will fail. You can use the intermediary functions [atof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atof) or [strtof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) (note `str`tof, not stof, why your second example fails) to convert these values, assuming you are sure they are actually in `float` form.

Comment: Okay. I altered the code to use `strtof` instead, but I still get a `error: 'strtof' was not declared in this scope` message when compiling.

Answer (score 1):

You are just converting a `char *` variable to `float` by typecasting. It will typecast value of the pointer to float, not the string to float.

You need to use functions such as `atof`, `strtof` to convert string to float. Or you can write your own function to to convert string to float.